# Buttons and Drop Downs duplicating in IE11 Word Add-in

Tags: internet-explorer-11, office-js

I have a Word 2016 Add-in (Office.js) built with Bootstrap 3 and jquery.

Windows 7 users are reporting (and I've seen) duplication and even triplication of buttons and dropdown menus when they return to Word 2016 after letting it sit for 45 minutes or so.

If you just refresh the page you get a correct, single version of these buttons and dropdowns.

Somehow IE11 is deciding on its own to update the page and, in doing so, creating duplicates.

The buttons and dropdowns all work. Refresh returns the page to the correct state.

Anyone have any direction to go or ideas on this?

---

Thank you for the detailed response & interest - apologies for the long delay in responding.

I've only seen this with one user, in the UK, running Windows 7 and Word 2016. I screenshared with him and saw the triplication in person...unfortunately didn't think to take screenshots of his experience. His IE11 install didn't have the "Install new versions automatically" checkbox that I have (Windows 10).

(Side note: the permutations of Word 2016 and IE11 are ending up being quite a handful - I have many institutional users and they don't control updates to one or both...hard to even figure out what they're using).

He had three versions of every Favorite button and three versions of each Group Drop Down.

A simple refresh of the page returned things to normal.

The buttons all worked while the dropdowns had all 3 sets of choices in the first iteration of the dropdown; the second and third iteration of a dropdown was empty.

He described the situation as resulting after he "lets Word sit without using it or my solution for 40+ minutes." He has used my solution extensively and hasn't reported seeing it during use.

The screenshot below shows things as they are normally.

In his situation, that first button (for example) named 'Link' would repeat after the list of buttons along with every single other blue Favorite button.

The Dropdowns (Argument etc.) would be similarly duplicated or triplicated (he hasn't seen 4 yet).

My code is pretty simple jquery/javascript. When you load the page or refresh it pulls content and builts these buttons and dropdowns dynamically. I don't understand a situation where the browser somehow reloads or duplicates content...

[image: Annotate Favorite Buttons and Dropdown Menus]

Comment: You mentioned both Word 2016 and IE 11. Are you seeing this in Word Online running in IE 11 or is this something happening within your add-in's task pane in Word 2016 for Windows?

Comment: it would be great if you can provide a screenshot. we are discussing the issue in the team and not very sure what buttons or dropdowns you are referring to.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT: I can't reproduce in any way shape or form...although my user is seeing the issue pretty regularly. I could ask him to try Word Online - just open it up and let it sit there to see if the same thing happens...will do.

Comment: My user ran my add-in in Word 2016 (Windows) and Word Online. The duplication did not occur online but it did occur (after ~30 minute wait) in the Windows version of Word 2016.